# A beginner Tic Tac Toe game, result problem (program doesn't care the first condition)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
board = [["___", "___", "___"],
         ["___", "___", "___"],
         ["___", "___", "___"]]

winning_possibilities = [[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
                         [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
                         [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]],
                         [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
                         [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],
                         [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]],
                         [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
                         [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]]

status_X = []
status_O = []

turnX = "X".center(3)
turnY = "O".center(3)

turn = 2

control = 1

counter = 0

tempCounter = 0

import random

print("\n"*10)
for i in board:
    print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)

while control == 1:
    try:
        for i in winning_possibilities:
            win_O = [z for z in i if z in status_O]
            win_X = [z for z in i if z in status_X]
            if counter > 4 and (len(win_O) == len(i) or (counter == 9 and len(win_O) == len(i))):
                print("O won, the game is over!" + "\n"*2)
                control = 0
                status_X = []
                status_O = []
                board = [["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"]]
                turn = 2
                counter = 0
                restart = str(input("To restart the game please press R.\n")).lower()
                if restart == "r":
                    print("\n"*10)
                    for i in board:
                        print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                    control = 1
            if len(win_X) == len(i) or (counter == 9 and len(win_X) == len(i)):
                print("X won, the game is over!" + "\n"*2)
                control = 0
                status_X = []
                status_O = []
                board = [["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"]]
                turn = 1
                counter = 0
                restart = str(input("To restart the game please enter R.\n")).lower()
                if restart == "r":
                    print("\n"*10)
                    for i in board:
                        print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                    control = 1
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            whoseTurn = turnX
        else:
            whoseTurn = turnY
        if control == 1:
            if whoseTurn == turnX:
                if counter > 0:
                    print("\n"*2 + "Your opponent played their turn, now it's your turn!" + "\n")
                else:
                    pass
                coordinateX = int(input("Choose a line from top to bottom to put {}. (1, 2, 3): ".format(whoseTurn)))
                if coordinateX > 0 and coordinateX < 4:
                    coordinateX -= 1
                    coordinateY = int(input("Choose a column from left to right to put {}. (1, 2, 3): ".format(whoseTurn)))
                    if coordinateY > 0 and coordinateY < 4:
                        coordinateY -= 1
                        if board[coordinateX][coordinateY] == "___":
                            board[coordinateX][coordinateY] = whoseTurn
                            status_X += [[coordinateX, coordinateY]]
                            counter += tempCounter
                            counter += 1
                            tempCounter = 0
                            turn += 1
                            print("\n"*5)
                            for i in board:
                                print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                        else:
                            tempCounter += counter
                            counter = 0
                            print("\n"*2 + "This spot is filled already! Please pick an empty spot!" +"\n"*2)
                else:
                     print("\n"*5)
                     for i in board:
                         print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                     print("\n"*2 + "Please just enter one of the numbers in the specified range." +"\n"*2)
            elif whoseTurn == turnY:
                    randomX = random.randint(0,2)
                    randomY = random.randint(0,2)
                    if board[randomX][randomY] == "___":
                        board[randomX][randomY] = whoseTurn
                        status_O += [[randomX, randomY]]
                        print("\n"*2 + "Now is your opponent's turn, wait him/her to play!" + "\n"*2)
                        counter += 1
                        turn +=1
                        print("\n"*5)
                        for i in board:
                            print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                    else:
                        randomX = random.randint(0,2)
                        randomY = random.randint(0,2)
        for i in winning_possibilities:
            if (len(win_O) != len(i) or len(win_X) != len(i)) and counter == 9:
                print("Draw!" + "\n"*2)
                control = 0
                status_X = []
                status_O = []
                board = [["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"],
                         ["___", "___", "___"]]
                counter = 0
                restart = str(input("To restart the game please enter R.\n")).lower()
                if restart == "r":
                    print("\n"*10)
                    for i in board:
                        print(" "*28, *i, sep=" "*3, end="\n"*3)
                    control = 1
    except ValueError:
        tempCounter += counter
        counter = 0
        print("\n"*2 + "Please just enter one of the numbers in the specified range." +"\n"*2)
    except IndexError:
        continue
    except NameError:
        pass
```

I am a beginner in Python and I am practicing. I have found a Tic Tac Toe game code and tried to understand what the developer made, after I understood I have developed this game and even improved also. But there is a bug that I can't fix and understand why it happens.

I have a counter variable and it is increasing +1 every turn. When it becomes to 9, the game result means draw. But there is a scenario also, if the player won the game on the 9th round, the  game result shouldn't be draw, so I put this code:

```
if (len(win_O) != len(i) or len(win_X) != len(i)) and counter == 9:
```

Instead of this one:

```
if counter == 9:
```

But still no fixed, the program doesn't care the first part of the condition. I hope someone can figure out the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Simplify the logic. Check for a win first. If there's no win, check if `counter == 9` and then declare a draw.

Comment: I did that but still  no fix, what I am doing wrong?

for i in winning_possibilities:
            if len(win_O) == len(i) or len(win_X) == len(i):
                continue
            else:
                if counter == 9:
                    print("Draw!" + "\n"*2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variables `win_O` and `win_x` are out of scope. Because you first defined them in the `try` block, they are not reachable outside of that block of code. So in:

```py
if (len(win_O) != len(i) or len(win_X) != len(i)) and counter == 9:
```

`win_O` and `win_x` are undefined. Try to define `win_O` and `win_x` sooner in the code, perhaps after `status_O = []` on line 15:

```py
status_X = []
status_O = []
win_0 = []
win_x = []
```